# No visible @interface for 'UIResponder' declares the selector 'viewDidAppear'

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface, parse-platform, appdelegate

I am making a login page for an application using Parse.
I get the error "visible @interface for 'UIResponder' declares the selector 'viewDidAppear'" 
I also get "visible @interface for 'UIResponder' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:present'"

So, in my AppDelegate.m I have:

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];//I GET THE ERROR HERE

    if (![PFUser currentUser]) { // No user logged in
        // Create the log in view controller
        PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
        [logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

        // Create the sign up view controller
        PFSignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[PFSignUpViewController alloc] init];
        [signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

       // Assign our sign up controller to be displayed from the login controller
        [logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController];

        // Present the log in view controller
        [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];//I GET THE ERROR HERE

        }
    }
```

In my AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end

// Implement both delegates
@interface DefaultSettingsViewController :
    UIViewController <PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

How can I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Why do you have a method (`viewDidAppear:`) from `UIViewController` in your app delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Your superclass needs to be a `UIViewController` subclass. In your code, it's a `UIResponder` subclass.

But I think the reason is that you're putting code that should go in a view controller into the app delegate. Move the `viewDidAppear:` method to the view controller where it needs to be.

Comment: The app delegate should not extend `UIViewController`.